# HP G8 server and disks

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hp

I'm looking to get an HP G8 server to create a ZFS based file server solution.

One of the things that I read is that starting with G8, HP Changed their caddies, and it now performs disks check to make sure the disks are branded as HP. If not, they'll appear as degraded.

Since I don't care so much about HP disks (I prefer to save the money and buy 3rd party disks, after all, it's for my home lab use), so I would like to ask:

- If I'll connect the backplane to another LSI/AVAGO RAID card - will the disks work?
- Will I get all the *correct* status from the disks on the OS level? (I'll be using Linux)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. Non HP or G7 and before disks won't get detected on a Gen 8 server.